# Opening a URL with a QR code

Tags: url, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I want to see if I could make a QR code that, once scanned, takes you to a database showing you files. Each QR code will have different files. I don't know if I have explained this well enough, so here's a step-by-step:

1. QR Code gets scanned.
2. QR Code then opens a special page where different QR Codes are assigned to different folders.

All I wanted to know was how I would do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possibilities with QR-codes. Even openening a link.
Try searching google: https://www.google.be/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=make%20qr%20code

Just one example: http://www.qr-code-generator.com/?PID=100&gclid=CjwKEAjwru6oBRDDp4jRj4bL_xASJADJ2obyqhvGMbuk0ySlRIpxYmdtKbLwegkTMWX4-HrOkeYPfhoCJ3Pw_wcB

I really can't list all the possibilities here :-)